# How to handle JWT and refresh tokens with multiple parallel requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, refresh-token

## My scenario

In my scenario I have a web app that calls some API endpoints to fetch data. On the API side the user is authenticated using a JWT token. In order to improve security, the JWT token is short-lived and the API provides a refresh-token that can be used along with the expired token to request a new pair of JWT and refresh-token.

The user is authenticated on the web app side using cookie authentication. In this authentication cookie I stored both the JWT token and refresh-token (with some other claims).

The client never makes calls directly to the API. The client makes a request to the web app, that when needed calls the API using the token extracted from the authentication cookie.

If the token is expired, it refreshes it using the refresh-token.

## The problem

This works fine with a single request, but the problem is when I have a page that makes multiple calls in parallel. When the token is expired, the first call is made, the token is refreshed and so the cookie and all works fine. But the others requests, that have been sent before the updated cookie is returned, fail as the refresh token cannot be used again to ask for new tokens and this results in an error.

I used ASP.NET Core 6.0 for both API and web app.

**How can this scenario be managed?**

## What I'm currently using

The following is the helper class that I've implemented to call the API. This automatically manages expired tokens.

For brevity I posted just the method that allows to make `GET` calls, but the workflow is the same for `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`, `DELETE` .

**NOTE**: When a call to the API fails because of an expired token, my API sets the header `Token-Expired` with value `true` in the response (in the code I used the const string `CustomResponseHeaders.ExpiredTokenHeader`).

```
public class MyApiCaller : IApiCaller
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _apiClient;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private string _token;
        private string _refreshToken;

        public bool IsLoggedIn => _apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization != null;
        public Uri BaseUri { get; }

        public MyApiCaller (IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _apiClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiRootUrl"))
            };
            _apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            
            BaseUri = _apiClient.BaseAddress;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void SetCredentials(string token, string refreshToken)
        {
            _token = token;
            _refreshToken = refreshToken;
            _apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            _token = null;
            _refreshToken = null;
            _apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(Uri uri)
        {
            var response = await _apiClient.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                // All is good, return the response
                return response;
            else
            {
                // Check if the request failed because of an expired token
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && response.Headers.Contains(CustomResponseHeaders.ExpiredTokenHeader))
                {
                    // The request failed due to an expired token

                    // Try to refresh the token
                    bool refreshed = await RefreshTokenAsync();
                    if (!refreshed)
                        // Failed to refresh so return the original response
                        return response;

                    // Repeat the original request with the new token
                    return await GetAsync(uri);
                } else
                {
                    // It is not a token-related error
                    // Return the unsuccessful response
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> RefreshTokenAsync()
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RefreshTokenRequest
            {
                Token = _token,
                RefreshToken = _refreshToken
            });
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await _apiClient.PostAsync("identity/refresh-token", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                SuccessfulAuthResponse successfulAuth = await response.ToModelAsync<SuccessfulAuthResponse>(); // Custom method to desirialize a JSON response
                // Set new credentials
                SetCredentials(successfulAuth.Token, successfulAuth.RefreshToken);
                // Update the tokens in cookie
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.UpdateTokensInCookie(successfulAuth.Token, successfulAuth.RefreshToken);

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you authenticate via a cookie then why you transport the 3rd party authentication token back and forth also via that cookie? Just cache/distribute/share it on the server for the user authenticated via your cookie. The tokens seems to have no additional value to the client.

Comment: @Ralf This could be a solution, but I just don't want to store data server-side. Moreover using cookie authentication, the user can specify to remember their credentials (make the auth cookie persistent). If this is the case, how can I store the JWT and refresh-token server-side? Saving them in the cookie seemed a better solution to me. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Have you found a solution?